# git два репозитория на проект

Tags: git, project

Есть сторонний проект на github - ng2-admin, я его склонировал.
На основе ng2-admin я уже вояю что то свое.
Там постоянно выходят доработки, что я забираю по git pull.
Но мне так же хочется вести историю и своих наработок.

Как мне все это пушить во второй проект, к пр myproject?
То есть я забрал обновы с ng2-admin и myproject говорит, что есть новые файлы.
Так же когда я работаю над своей частью кода, что бы ng2-admin не мелькам мне что есть новый код, изменения в нем.

Как это все сделать в одной папке, я не знаю, но есть вот такая мысль...
Будут две папки ng2-admin и myproject.
Через rsync заганять код в myproject.

Если есть более изящный вариант по средствам самого git для одной директории, то конечно воспользовался бы лучше им.

Если можно, то поделитесь статьями, можно тут раскидать, можно пальцем ткнуть.
Любые мысли тоже приветствуются.

Comment: в git есть возможность добавить два remote (обычно он там один). И теперь можно будет пушить/пулить сразу в два.

Comment: @KoVadim, там будет выбор с какого pull забирать, а в какой push отправлять, или всегда в оба синхронно?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Самое первое, что нужно понять, это то, что в гите есть ветки локальные, а есть локальные ветки, к которым привязаны удаленные. Обычно, имя удаленной ветки совпадает с именем локальной. Но это "обычно".

Локальные ветки обычно называются так "master", "develop", а удаленные "origin/master", "origin/develop". origin - это просто название удаленного репозитория, синоним для  урла репозитория и имеет такое имя, потому что там принято хранить "оригинальный", "начальный" код.

Теперь разберем глубже.

Посмотреть добавленные удаленные репозитории

```
git remote show
```

там обычно будет origin.

Добавить ещё один (как пример, с гитхаба)

```
git remote add <имя> git@github.com:user/BBBB.git
```

можно добавить опцию `-f`, что бы подтянуло данные. `<имя>` - это имя репы для нас, пусть там будет second

Теперь, можно делать к примеру так

Сделаем ветку от мастера первого репозитория

```
git checkout -b test origin/master
```

и подмержим туда мастер второго

```
git merge second/master
```

( решаем кофликты, коммитим)

и теперь отправим эту ветку в второй репозиторий в ветку mytest

```
git push -u second mytest
```

эта команда и привяжет локальную ветку test c веткой mytest в второй репе. Последующие пуши в этой ветке будут отправлять именно ее в правильный репозиторий (конечно, если `push.default=simple`, но это сейчас по умолчанию). git pull подтянет изменения в этой ветке с правильного удаленного репозитория.

То есть, для Вас два (или больше) внешних репозитория будут выглядеть как один. Да, у них могут быть ветки с одинаковыми именами, но у Вас всегда есть возможность привязать их к удобным Вам названиям. Эти локальные названия веток кроме Вас никто не будет знать. Ветки можно мержить и ничего, что они "как бы находятся в разных репозиториях".

Также ещё понадобятся команды вида `git fetch origin`/`git fetch second` - утянуть изменения с удаленных репозиториев себе, но ничего не пытаться смержить (точнее - обновить привязанные локальные ветки).

P.S. Когда то я таким образом "мигрировал код" с одной репы компании в другую репу. Вот только репы были за впн, плюс разработчики переезжали на новую репу потихоньку и мне нужно было "допереносить код".

Answer (score 1):

На вашем месте, я бы посмотрел в сторону использования [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8) или [git subtree](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree). Оба похода позволят вам вести проект в одном git репозитории, но разделить с точки зрения git ваши наработки и сторонний проект. У каждого из них есть свои преимущества и недостатки. Если вы хотите использовать сторонний проект ng2-admin "as is", то больше подойдет submodule. Если вы хотите вносить изменения в ng2-admin непосредственно для своих нужд, то удобнее будет subtree, так как позволит вам делать и локальные изменения (и на выбор либо сливать их во внешний репозиторий проекта, либо оставить изменения только в локальном репозитории и периодически мерджить их с новыми изменениями с remote), так и изменения для remote. К сожалению, использование и subtree и submodule не даст возможности держать все в одной директории, но позволит использовать вложенную директорию для хранения ng2-admin, которая будет курироваться другим git репозиторием.

Вы можете использовать и 2 remote, как вам писали в комментарии, однако, это не избавит вас от надобности постоянного выбора ветки/репозитория для коммита, а также не даст сделать логическое разделение порций изменений для 2 репозиториев внутри проетка, так чтобы они не мешали друг другу.